# How to traverse through 2 javascript array of objects and create a third one?

Tags: javascript, object

I have two objects. obj2 has texts and obj1 has 3 subIbjId. How can I add the 'id' to obj2 based on obj1? 
For example: obj1 has 2 subObjId in the first object(1001, 1002). I want to count the number of subObjId obj1 has and iterate through obj1 and add the key and value of id for the  to obj2. If obj1 has two subObjId, then add id: 1 to the first two entries of obj2 and so on.

I am learning javascript and trying to solve some imaginary problems. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```js
var obj1 = { [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: ‘apple’,
  subObjId: [ 1001, 1002]
  subObjs: [
   {
   subId: 1001
   subName: ‘ant’,
   },
   {
   subId: 1002
   subName: ‘ball’,
   }
  ],
 },
 {
  {
  id: 2,
  name: ‘zebra’,
  subObjId: [ 1003]
  subObjs: [
   {
   subId: 1003
   subName: ‘cat’,
   }
  ],
 },
]
}

var obj2 = { [
 {
  text: ‘i am a text’
 },
 {
  text: ‘i am some random characters’
 },
 {
  text: ‘i am some numbers’
 }
] }


to become

finalObject = { [
 {
  id: 1,
  text: ‘i am a text’
 },
 {
  id: 1,
  text: ‘i am some random characters’
 },
 { 
  id: 2,
  text: ‘i am some numbers’
 }
] }
```

Comment: And did you try anything?

Comment: This syntax is incorrect - you can't have an array as the *only* thing in an object literal - without keys of values `{ [] }`. Do you want *an array* or *an object* to hold the data?

Comment: It is not very clear what the relation between the two sets of data is. Can you be more explicit about how to link one to the other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!!

```js
var obj1 =  [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: 'apple',
  subObjId: [ 1001, 1002]
 },
  {
  id: 2,
  name: 'zebra',
  subObjId: [ 1003]
 }
]

var obj2 =  [
 {
  text: 'i am a text'
 },
 {
  text: 'i am some random characters'
 },
 {
  text: ' am some numbers'
 }
] 

let index = 0;
let start = 0;
obj1.map(data1=>{
  index += data1.subObjId.length;
  for(var i=start;i<index;i++){
    obj2[i]['id'] = data1.id;
  }
  start = i;
})

console.log(obj2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to extract an array of all `subObjs` items

   - also [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) them into their parent's `id` property only.
2. Perform another mapping operation that copies the contents of a matching object in `obj2` and adds an `id`.

   - For convenience, this uses the second argument to `Array#map`, which sets the `this` context inside the callback.

Also uses [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for compactness and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for making copies:

```js
var obj1 = [ { id: 1, name: 'apple', subObjId: [1001, 1002], subObjs: [ { subId: 1001, subName: 'ant' }, { subId: 1002, subName: 'ball' } ] }, { id: 2, name: 'zebra', subObjId: [1003], subObjs: [ { subId: 1003, subName: 'cat', } ], }, ];

var obj2 = [ { text: 'i am a text' }, { text: 'i am some random characters' }, { text: 'i am some numbers' } ];

var finalObject = obj1
  //1. flatMap into a single array
  .flatMap(({id, subObjs}) => subObjs
    .map(sub => ({id})) //take only the parent ID for each sub object
  )// result: [{id: 1}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}]
  .map(function({id}, index) {
    return { id, ...this[index] } //2. create a new object with the id and the content of a matching object from the other array
  }, obj2);// <- set the `this` context for the callback

console.log(finalObject);
```

It can also be done as a single operation when flatmapping by setting the `this` context to a copy of the second array (to avoid mutating `obj2`), then taking items off the front of the new array with [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift):

```js
var obj1 = [ { id: 1, name: 'apple', subObjId: [1001, 1002], subObjs: [ { subId: 1001, subName: 'ant' }, { subId: 1002, subName: 'ball' } ] }, { id: 2, name: 'zebra', subObjId: [1003], subObjs: [ { subId: 1003, subName: 'cat', } ], }, ];

var obj2 = [ { text: 'i am a text' }, { text: 'i am some random characters' }, { text: 'i am some numbers' } ];

var finalObject = obj1.flatMap(function({id, subObjs}) { 
    return subObjs.map(sub => ({ id, ...this.shift() }))
  }, [...obj2]);// <- copy obj2 as the `this` context

console.log(finalObject);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this snippet

```js
var obj1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'apple',
    subObjId: [1001, 1002],
    subObjs: [{
      subId: 1001,
      subName: 'ant',
    },
    {
      subId: 1002,
      subName: 'ball',
    }
    ],
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'zebra',
    subObjId: [1003],
    subObjs: [{
      subId: 1003,
      subName: 'cat',
    }],
  },
]


var obj2 = [
  {
    text: 'i am a text'
  },
  {
    text: 'i am some random characters'
  },
  {
    text: 'i am some numbers'
  }
]

var finalObject = obj1.map(function (value, index) {
  return {
    id: value.id,
    text: obj2[index].text
  }
})

console.log(finalObject)
```

Comment: Produces two outputs, whereas OP expects three - `id: 1` should be in it twice, because of the two `subObjs` items.